# Ordered union on spark RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to do a sort on key of key-record pairs using apache spark. The key is 10 bytes long and the value is about 90 bytes long. In other words I am trying to replicate the sort benchmark Databricks used to [break the sorting record](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html). One of the things I noticed from the documentation is that they sorted on key-line-number pairs as opposed to key-record pairs to probably be cache/tlb friendly. I tried to replicate this approach but have not found a suitable solution. Here is what I have tried:

```
var keyValueRDD_1 = input.map(x => (x.substring(0, 10), x.substring(12, 13)))
var keyValueRDD_2 = input.map(x => (x.substring(0, 10), x.substring(14, 98))
var result = keyValueRDD_1.sortByKey(true, 1) // assume partitions = 1
var unionResult = result.union(keyValueRDD_2) 
var finalResult = unionResult.foldByKey("")(_+_)
```

When I do a union on the result RDD and keyValueRDD_2 RDD and print the output of the unionResultRDD, the result and keyValueRDD_2 are not interleaved. In other words, it looks like the unionResult RDD has the keyValueRDD_2 contents followed by the result RDD contents. However, when I do a foldByKey operation which combines the values of same key into a single key-value pair, the sorted order is destroyed. I need to do a fold by key operation in order to save the result as the original key-record pair. Is there an alternate rdd function that could be used to achieve this?

Any tips or suggestions would be quite useful. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `RDD.zip` and/or `RDD.zipWithIndex`?

Comment: My understanding of RDD zip is that it will zip up the elements of the two RDD element wise. So, while one RDD is ordered, the other RDD is not ordered, and it will lead to the same issue that @daniel pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `union` method just puts two RDDs one after the other, except if they have the same partitioner. Then it joins the partitions.

***What you want to do is impossible.***

When you have one RDD sorted (`keyValueRDD_1`) and another unsorted RDD with the same keys (`keyValueRDD_2`) then the only way to get the second RDD sorted is to sort it.

The existence of the sorted RDD does not help us sort the second RDD.

The Databricks [article](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html) talks about an optimization that happens locally on the executors. After the shuffle step, the records are roughly sorted. Each partition now covers a range of keys, but the partitions are unsorted.

Now you have to sort each partition locally, and this is where the prefix optimization helps with cache locality.

Comment: I see. Yes, this makes sense. So, either this prefix optimization is already inbuilt in the spark-engine or one should code it in such a way that this optimization is used is something I need to explore. But yes, I see how the above is impossible and I was leaning towards that outcome. Thanks @Daniel.